# How can I load an i18n json from a CMS with i18next?

Tags: next.js, internationalization, i18next, graphcms

I am using https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next and rather than hardcoding the files, I want to use HygraphCMS (formerly `GraphCMS`) to provide those strings. What's the best way to approach this?

If I wait for an async request, it'll slow things down. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you had a look at dynamically loading the translations on the client-side (https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend/tree/master/example/next)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution here would depend on how you have the rest of the Next.js project set up and how much you want to avoid an async request. I've described two approaches I would consider below. Both examples assume you're using Next.js and hosting on Vercel, but it should be possible and similar through other platforms.

**1. Build script to store locally (without async request)**

Start by writing a script to fetch all the translations and store them locally in the project (just as Aldabil21 said).

After that, you can create a [deploy webhook](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/git/deploy-hooks) and [call it from your CMS](https://hygraph.com/docs/api-reference/basics/webhooks#triggers) whenever a change is made; this will ensure that the translations are always kept up-to-date. An issue with this could be that the build runs too often, so you may want to add some conditions here to prevent that, such as only calling the webhook from the CMS when the translations content changes.

**2. Using incremental static regeneration (with async request)**

Of course, if you're using [incremental static regeneration](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration), you might reconsider fetching the translations using [getStaticProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props) as the request is not made for each visitor.

The result of the request to the CMS's translation collection would be cached on Vercel's Edge network and then shared amongst each visitor, so only the first request after the cache has expired will trigger the full request. The maximum age for the caching of static files is 31 days, so this delay when requesting fresh data could be infrequent enough to be acceptable. Note that you have to enable this manually [by setting the `revalidate` prop](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#revalidate) in the return object of `getStaticProps`.

You could even mitigate this request further (depending on your project setup) by querying only for the language that is currently used, and querying a new language client-side only when it is requested by the visitor (or possibly once the page is idle or the language switcher is opened). If you have many languages, this reduction will reduce the download time substantially.

If you do go the `getStaticProps` route and are using Next.js >`12.2.0` then you could also create a CMS webhook to call the [on-demand revalidation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration#using-on-demand-revalidation) endpoint whenever a page is updated, which will cause the fresh translations to be stored in cache before a user gets a chance to request it, removing the delay for all users. Or you could use the webhook in the same way as mentioned in 1 and trigger a new build (with the new translations) every time the translation collection is updated.

Answer (score 2):

I pumped into similar issue before, what I did was I created a script that runs before the `dev` and `build` commands, something like:

```
// ...
"scripts": {
  // ....
  "trans": "node ./scripts/get-i18n.js",
  "dev":"npm run trans && next dev",
  "build":"npm run trans && next build"
}
// ...
```

And you write a script `get-i18n.js` to fetch you translations from the CMS and save them in the directory you chosed in the `i18n` setup.

The downside of this approach that if the translation changed in the CMS you would need to restart the server everytime, or run the script manually in another shell to make the fetch and update the strings.